# .net 4 DataGridView does not update the database sqldatasource after adding, updating and deleting rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, sqldatasource

I'm working on a big project and don't have much time to dwell on each problem, I'm using Windows Forms, particularly the DataGridView. I just added a data source that would query a table on the database. The enable add, delete, and edit properties are checked. I created this DataGridView through drag and drop, and adding a datasource. The query works fine when I run the program, the table appears on my DataGridView, I'm able to add, edit and delete rows on the DataGridView, but when I query the table through SQL Server Management Studio, the records in the table remain the same. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you updating the database when the DataGridView has rows edited/added/deleted?  You don't show any code so it's hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: How can I set it up, that when I add/edit/delete rows on the DataGridView, the changes will also be stored on the database? There's really no code, I just dragged a DataGridView and bound it to a datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. I've added a button named "Save Changes".

First I make the initial  declarations:

```
    private SqlDataAdapter da;
    private DataTable dt;
    private SqlCommandBuilder sqlCommandBuilder = null;
    private SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=......");
```

This is the Code for loading the DataGridView which populates it:

```
     private void DataGridView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Con.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM tbl", Con);
        sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);


        dt = new DataTable(); 
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        Con.Close();
    }
```

This is the code for the Save Changes button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SqlCommandBuilder local_SqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

                local_SqlCommandBuilder.ConflictOption = System.Data.ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;

                da.UpdateCommand = local_SqlCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();

                da.Update(((System.Data.DataTable)this.dataGridView1.DataSource));

                ((System.Data.DataTable)this.dataGridView1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The datasource needs to have insert/update/delete commands in order for the gridview to work, and it sounds like it just has a select command.

Comment: How am I going to make it have insert/update/delete commands? This control was very misleading, I thought that when you enabled adding/deleting/updating, it would do so on the database too. Apparently, its only up to the DataGridView.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using a SQLDataSource object to bind the grid to? It should have a SelectCommand, UpdateCommand, DeleteCommand, and InsertCommand - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1a0y8f.aspx  It won't know how to perform these operations in the database unless you give it a sql query or stored procedure to run. Alternatively, you could handle the events in your code-behind and call these things manually.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you do need to specifically run an update command.

Here's a link that may help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx

And here's one that discusses how to auto save to SQL Server, if that's relevant:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12846/Auto-Saving-DataGridView-Rows-to-a-SQL-Server-Data

This is one reason why I like the Entity Framework/MVC. Very simple data manipulation :D I'd suggest you check it out if you're intersted/have spare time.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using dbnavigator after you done with table you should click on save button on dbnavigator because add and edit and delete do not save in database until you click on save button in dbnavigator.